# Is @Binding possible in a ForEach list using list's id?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

Using @State in ParentView and @Binding in ChildView we can make a connection between values of 2 variables in a print and child view. Using code like this:

```
ChildView(valueFromParent: $valueInParent)
```

Having valueInParent in ParentView using @State and valueFromParent in ChildView using @Binding. That way those 2 variables are related now and changing one will change another.

Is it possible though to have this binding between two views in a ForEach loop using rows' id numbers? Something like this:

```
ForEach((1...15), id: \.self) {item in
    ChildView(valueFromParent[item]: self.$valueInParent[item])
}
```

I am aware of another way - creating an array of item to pass to the list with IDs inside an array:

```
@State private var list = [
        (id: 0, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 1, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 2, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 3, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 4, model: ListItemModel())
    ]
```

**Edit**: But I wish to avoid the above array with a fixed list of items.

I would like to create a simple prototype using just a ForEach loop like this: ForEach((1...15), id: .self). The problem is I don't know how to access a var's value from a particular row in the list.

Comment: It is possible, but think twice if it is really what you need, because `ForEach(range)` is constant container, ie. you won't be able to change its size, ie. adding/removing items in model container either have no effect (on add) or crash (on remove) due to out of range exception.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the limitations. Yes, still it’s what I need. It is for prototyping purposes. To create a list very fast and change something inside the rows. It’s not for production

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo module of possible approach. Hope it will be helpful.

**Update: Provided two variants - for array with model and for dictionary with model**

*1. Variant with array as container for model*

```
import SwiftUI

struct Model {
    var name: String
    var value: Int

    init(_ name: String, _ value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct DetailsView : View {
    @Binding var item: Model
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Name")
            TextField("", text: $item.name)
        }
    }
}

struct Main: View {
    @State var models = [Model("A", 1), Model("B", 2), Model("C", 3), Model("D", 4)]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<models.count) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(item: self.$models[i])) {
                        Text("Model: \(self.models[i].name)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct DemoMainDetailByID: View {
    var body: some View {
        Main()
    }
}

struct DemoMainDetailByID_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoMainDetailByID()
    }
}
```

*2. Variant with dictionary as container for model*

```
struct Main: View {
    @State var models: [Int: Model] = [1: Model("A", 1), 2: Model("B", 2), 3: Model("C", 3), 4: Model("D", 4)]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(1...4, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(item: Binding(self.$models[i])!)) {
                        Text("Model: \(self.models[i]!.name)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I wanted to hold id as countable number. Like this for example: `ForEach((1...15), id: \.self)`. And don't use an array. Having array, changing from 3 to 30 rows is more time consuming than with (1...15). If I use countable number, what is the equivalent of `\(self.models[i].name)`? I was hoping that using @Binding in a ForEach list I could have an access to let's say var valueFromParent from row 9. Using something like this: valueFromParent[9]

Comment: Do you mean dictionary as a container for model?

Comment: I don't know if my answer is correct. I am new to coding ;) What I mean - no model at all.

Comment: Just a ForEach list with ChildView with defined row. And In this row a clickable Star that would change a value: favourite or not. True or false. But I would like to access each row in ParentView and check: is row 3 favourite or not? And show different text outside of the list depending on the value: Text(item[3].valueFromParent ? "On" : "Off") 
In a similar question you've advised using ObservableObject. I would like to make things simpler (if possible) and use @Binding in ForEach. I am passing values between just 2 views.

Comment: Thanks, your second example is almost what I am trying to achieve. But can @State var models be simpler? Like an empty array. Or 1 element array. Because it has 4 items inside. What will happen if I will change ForEach(1...4 to be ForEach(1...40?

Comment: In such case I recommend to consider transparent `Binding(get: set:)` constructor, which would redirect calls to that one instance. You don't even need a container, which was mentioned in original question.

Comment: What container you are referring to, Asperi?

Comment: `private var list`

Comment: Ah, it's a misunderstanding. Sorry. I wrote that I am aware of using array. But I would like to avoid it and make things flexible using just countable numbers in ForEach. I have edited the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Your second Answer is almost perfect I think. But instead of fixed array I would like to use something more flexible. So I could change ForEach(1...4 to any number I want. And also, I get an error when I move DetailsView to separate file. It gives me: Cannot invoke 'DetailsView' with an argument list of type '(item: Binding<Model>)'